# Does mapping sorted input to unsorted output prove $P\ne NP$

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider two sets of the same length that both contain every $n$-bit value. The first set is sorted, but the second set is unsorted and randomly arranged. Since both sets contain all possible $n$-bit values, they each have a size of $n*2^n$ bits. Now the task is to find what value in the sorted set, $a_i$, corresponds to the given value in the unsorted set, $b_i$. Linear search would need to be performed on the unsorted set resulting in a worst-case of $O(2^n)$. However, if we are given a possible solution, $a_i$, that needs to be verified, then binary search could be used on the sorted set to find $b_i$ and compare the result. This would be $O(n)$. Also, it can be assumed that finding $a_i$ and $b_i$ given $i$ is $O(1)$.

Am I wrong in letting $n$ be the input size rather than the size of sets themselves? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The size of the sets would be O (2^n), therefore linear search works in linear time in the size of the set.

Comment: @gnasher729 So linear search would be $O(2^n)$ on the set, right?